# Почему эллиптическое?

Tags: синтаксис

На сайте http://rus-exam.ru/info/reference/item/199-sinonimiya-pridatochnyih

пишут, что 5. Если придаточное определительное представляет собой эллиптическое предложение, то его замена обособленным определением невозможна из-за отсутствия глагола-сказуемого.

Например: Вы выбираете ялик, который к вам поближе... (Л. Толстой).

Почему придаточное определительное - эллиптическое?

Answer (score 8):

В этом предложении опущено сказуемое: ялик, который (находится) поближе. А раз глагола- сказуемого нет, то и причастие от него не образуешь.

Comment: Я думаю, что вопрос в другом - почему предложение называют эллиптическом? При чем тут геометрическая фигура "эллипс"?

Comment: Это тоже понятно:эллипс - пропуск, опущение, недостача.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%81
Потому и эллиптическое - с пропуском сказуемого. Ларf верно ответила.Причастие образуется от глагола, а глагола нет - нет и причастия.

Comment: Да, спасибо, @Людмила. Теперь ясно.